# What does Feynman mean by "potential energy is changed only by the addition of a constant"?

Tags: potential-energy

I'm reading "The Feynman Lectures Vol.1"
Chapter 14. http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_14.html

> "The quantity U(1)−U(2)U(1)−U(2) is called the change in the potential
>   energy, and we call UU the potential energy. We shall say that when
>   the object is located at position 22, it has potential energy U(2)U(2)
>   and at position 11 it has potential energy U(1)U(1). If it is located
>   at position PP, it has zero potential energy. If we had used any other
>   point, say QQ, instead of PP, it would turn out (and we shall leave it
>   to you to demonstrate) that the potential energy is changed only by
>   the addition of a constant. Since the conservation of energy depends
>   only upon changes, it does not matter if we add a constant to the
>   potential energy. Thus the point PP is arbitrary."

Basically, I don't get anything after the "If we had used any other point ..."

Comment: Are you implying that by "if we use any other point instead of P" he was talking about using a different "origin"?

Comment: As defined by newton's first law, all origins are equally valid

Comment: Well, I thought he was choosing a point relative to the origin, like he chose point 1 and point 2.

Comment: that includes change in velocity

Comment: Where does velocity come in?

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a potential energy diagram it might look like this.

[image]

Difference in potential energy between position $P$ and position $1$ is $U(1)-U(P)$ - **I have not put $U(P) = 0$ but remember that in Feynman's text it is equal to zero**.

Difference in potential energy between position $P$ and position $2$ is $U(2)-U(P)$

Difference in potential energy between position $1$ and position $2$ is $U(1)-U(2)$

Now the potential energy at position $Q$ is $U(Q) = U(P) +k$ where $k$ is the "addition of a constant".

Difference in potential energy between position $Q$ and position $1$ is $U(1)-U(Q) = U(1) - (U(P) + k$) - "addition of a constant $k$".

Which can be written as:
$U(1)-U(Q) = U(1) - U(P) - k$

Difference in potential energy between position $Q$ and position $1$ is $U(2)-U(Q) = U(2) - U(P) - k$  - "addition of a constant $k$".

However the difference in potential energy between position $1$ and position $2$ is still $U(1)-U(2)$

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be as follows:
Difference in potential energy between position QQ and position 11 is U(1)−U(Q)=U(1)−U(P)+kU(1)−U(Q)=U(1)−U(P)-k - "addition of a constant kk".

U(Q)=UP+k. So when subtracting, we will subtract the whole, so the sign on k gets reversed too.

Comment: Why does Feynman say that U(1)-U(2) is the change in the potential energy? It would seem like it would be the negative of the change in the potential energy... Because if an object at point 1 goes to point 2, in a gravitational field say, and point 1 is higher than point 2, U(1)-U(2) > 0, but in reality potential energy was lost. Shouldn't it be the other way around?